# Using Pandas in Python 3, how do I filter out repeat strings in a column within a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to analyze a dataset containing a list of names and their frequency in a particular year. I would like to eliminate repeat names and output the top 10 different girls names in the dataset. I was able to get the top 10 year/name combinations, but I want to get the top 10 names overall:

```py
import glob 
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('data/years/*.txt')
data_list = []
Count = 0

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(f)
    data_list.append(data)

df = pd.concat(data_list)
Female_df = df[df['Sex'] == 'F']
Male_df = df[df['Sex'] == 'M']

Count_female = len(Female_df.index)
Count_male = len(Male_df.index)

Top_10_Female = Female_df.sort_values('Count', ascending = False)
Top_10_Female
```

**Output:**

```
      Sex   Year     Name   Count
1234    F   1947    Linda   99685
1216    F   1948    Linda   96210
1183    F   1949    Linda   91013
1186    F   1950    Linda   80439
1354    F   1921    Mary    73983
1234    F   1951    Linda   73970
1394    F   1924    Mary    73533
```

**Expected Output:**

```
      Sex   Name
1234    F   Linda
1354    F   Mary
...
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, so I won't just give you the answer. Look into some of the methods that are available for dataframes. If you need to remove duplicates, there is a method that does just that with extensive documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the direction! The problem is practice my firm assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If would like to get the sum of the number of occurrences of the name, you can use 'groupby':

```
df.groupby('Name')['Count'].sum()
```

Please check out the documentation on [pandas.Series.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html#pandas.Series.groupby)

In case you only want to remove the duplicate names, you could also use 'drop_duplicates' (specifying the column):

```
df.drop_duplicates('Name')
```

Documentation: [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)